# Solving for RC circuit transfer function

Tags: analog, impedance, kirchhoffs-laws, transfer-function

How do I calculate the transfer function of this circuit? \$H(s) = \dfrac{V_o}{V_i}\$

I apply the Kirchhoff's law at the node \$V_x\$ but I still have \$V_x\$ as unknown : 
\$\dfrac{V_x - V_i}{R1}+\dfrac{V_x - V_o}{R2}+(V_x - 0)sC = 0\$

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feailD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Here's a hint:  The current through R2 is 0A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the current through R2 is zero, Vo = Vx. You can calculate Vo (and Vx) just using the known expression of a voltage divider:

$$
V_o = V_x = \frac{\frac{1}{sC}}{\frac{1}{sC} + R_1} V_i= \frac{1}{R_1Cs + 1} V_i.
$$